# How to replicate image effect from youtube channel banner with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to replicate the "effect" of the image staying in the center when scrolling down the Youtube channel page. I don't really know how to describe it but I want an image on top of my website that behaves like the image of a youtube channel banner...

for example on Pew Die Pies Page: https://www.youtube.com/user/PewDiePie
the text "milestone" stays in the center when you scroll down until there's nothing left

Any ideas how to do this with CSS?

Comment: there you are https://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/

Comment: i think parallax is basically what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: you could do it with pure CSS, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_parallax
`background-attachment: fixed`, with some more changes of course